# MOJO perl Deprecated warnings

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo

I am learning Mojo, this is my first script and it works fine - that is it does what i want it to do.

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::Collection;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent ->new;
my $dom = Mojo::DOM ->new;

$dom = $ua->get('http://lalalala....')->res->dom;

open (my $file_zlec, "> zlc2012.csv") or die "couldn't open file!";
binmode $file_zlec, ":utf8";

for my $zlec($dom->find('table.tbl_zlc')->each){
    print "$i \n"; $i++;

    wypisz($zlec, 'td.tbl_zlc_d1',1);
    print $file_zlec"\n";

}

sub wypisz{ 
    my $ch= $_[0]-> find($_[1])->children;

    if ($_[2]==1){
        my $tekst = $ch->text;
        print $file_zlec "$tekst;";
    }   

    my $href= $ch->map(attr => 'href');
    if (not $href=~/lalala\.pl/g) {$href="www.lalala.pl".$href};
    print $file_zlec "$href;";
```

}

However, a get a lot of warnings regarding "children", "text" and "attr":
'Mojo::Collection::AOUTOLOAD (..) is DEPRECATED in favor of MOJO::Collection::map at (..)'
'Stringifacation support in Mojo::Collection::AOUTOLOAD (...) is DEPRECATED in favor of Mojo::Collection::join at (..)

I thought i was doing smth wrong, but I followed the example at http://mojocasts.com/e5 EXCACTLY and got the same warnings

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent ->new;
print $ua->get('http://mojolicio.us')->res->dom->html->head->title;
```

My questions are:
1. should i worry? like i said, scripts works fine
2. if ans(1) is no, is there a way to turn this off? i can't see anything in a command line..

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."*

Comment: I have had to flag your question for closure, as there is no way to debug your program with the information you have given. If you want answers then you must provide us with code that we can *run* and see the errors that you are getting. You have removed the most useful parts of the error messages, and have typed them in instead of copy/pasting them to your post.

Comment: thakns, i've editet the question with example that gives me the same warning like my script - i hope that is enogh

Comment: If you mean the three lines of code at the end, then that runs cleanly. Are you saying that it throws errors for you?

Comment: Yes. theese 3 lines are the whole script and i got 3 warnings - regarding html, head and title - Mojo::"AUTOLOAD (html) is deprecated...

one more thing maybe is important.. i had problems with downloading the Mojo package from the command line (using cpan) and finally i've downloaded it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay it looks like these deprecations have been added recently. For example the AUTOLOAD deprecation was introduced at the end of October this year, and my version of Mojolicious preceded that so I wasn't seeing the messages you were getting. I've now upgraded my installation and understand the problem.

Unfortunately, the Mojolicious *DEPRECATED* messages are generated by the `Carp` module and they don't respond to the `no warnings` pragma. The only way I know to disable then is to set the warning handler to a null subroutine, like this

```
$SIG{__WARN__} == sub {  };
```

but that is very heavy-handed as it silences *all* warnings instead of just the nuisance ones you are seeing.

Since the facility you are using is deprecated, it is likely to be removed from the Mojolicious suite in the near future, so it is best anyway if you learn to adopt the new standard from the outset.

The message says

```
Mojo::DOM::AUTOLOAD (html) is DEPRECATED in favor of Mojo::DOM::children
```

which means that they would prefer that you used `$dom->children('html')` instead of just `$dom->html`. But `children` returns a `Mojo::Collection` object, which is a *set* of nodes, so you need to select the first item of that collection. That turns

```
$dom->html->head->title
```

into the cumbersome

```
$dom->children('html')->first->children('head')->first->children('title')->first
```

so it is far better to use the `at` method which takes a CSS3 expression, and you can write

```
$dom->at('html > head > title')
```

which is fine, and generates no warnings. Note that it isn't an exact replacement for the `children`/`first` chain, as the entire document is being searched for a `title` node that is a child of a `head` node that is a child of an `html` node. But since the only place that this can occur is at the root of the document, the result is identical. Even this can be fixed by using the CSS3 item `:root` in place of `html`.

The complete program would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojolicious;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $dom = $ua->get('http://mojolicio.us')->res->dom;

print $dom->at('html > head > title')->text;
```

**output**

```
      Mojolicious - Perl real-time web framework
```

Comment: thank you! that is exhaustive answer, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

*"should i worry"*

You should aim to remove *all* warning messages that a program generates. You first need to understand exactly why you are getting them, and then you can make the choice to write your code differently or to temporarily disable the warnings once you are certain that the problem is benign.

As a guide, I disable warnings in much less than one percent of my programs. They are almost always an indication of a coding problem that can and should be resolved.